# How LastModifiedby (field) updated for true changes

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, field-update, update, lastmodifieddate

I have a field named LastmodifiedBy that have a lookup with the objet User and it changes and takes the name of the user without making any changes or modification in my record , I just have to navigate through the panes of my record without making any changes and I find it changing ( I find that the field take the name of the current user even if he did not make any change ).

Does this have a solution?
I want him to take the username if only he made a modification

Comment: When you say "navigate through the panes of my record" do you mean in a standard Lightning Record Page or is this in a custom Visualforce page? If a Lightning Record Page, do you have some custom LWC(s) on the page? Basically what you report makes me think you have some custom processing that is causing a DML operation to be performed as a side-effect, perhaps setting field(s) to their current value(s), and that the solution will be to identify this processing and update the custom work to avoid doing this.

Comment: @Phil W When I say "navigate through the panes of my record" I you mean in a custom lightning web component , I have 3 components and  when I just navigate to one of them and i return to the details page ( Page layout ) I find that the  LastmodifiedBy is changed even if  I did not make any change

Comment: If you wrote those components, check for inappropriate DML in one of the Apex methods that these LWCs invoke. If someone else wrote them, check with them.

Comment: @Phil W , ok , thank you , I will verify the DML

Comment: @Phil W  , I tried to check the DML and checked all the method , but As I am new in salesforce , I could not find the issus , could you please give me more details

Comment: Who wrote the components? Can you talk to them? In the context of "inappropriate updates", the DML you are looking for would be calls to `Database.update(...)`, `Database.upsert(...)` or use of the `update` or `upsert` keywords.

Comment: @Phil W thank you for your help , I checked all the method , The trigger also and now I fond that the problem is with a flow that make the update of the record